# eigenvalues of $AA^T$ and $A^TA$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, transpose

Is it true (and under which conditions) that the products of an non-square matrix $A$ and its transpose and vice versa (so the product of the transpose and $A$) share the same eigenvalues (multiplicities omitted)?

Comment: They share all non-zero eigenvalues

Comment: It's easy to see that ^ because the operators are intertwined via $A$ (or $A^T$).

Comment: Of course. Thx. Subject closed.

Comment: You should accept one of the answers if they answered it to your satisfaction. This prevents the post from being unnecessarily bumped by Community.

Comment: The more general fact is that $AB$ and $BA$ share the same nonzero eigenvalues with the same multiplicities. This is true even if neither $A$ nor $B$ are invertible (or square) so Cameron's argument doesn't work. See https://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/06/05/ab-ba-and-the-spectrum/ for details.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Oh doh. I didn't mean necessarily to imply invertibility, but rather that $A(BA) =(AB) A$ provided that the products make sense, so that $A$ kind of acts like an intertwining operator would. I'm not sure what the proper term is. It's the underpinnings of SUSYQM though.

Answer (score 5):

They share all nonzero eigenvalues. Basically, you "pad" the shorter list with zeroes.

One way to see it is to first note that $\ker A^TA=\ker A$. Now, if $A^TAx=\lambda x$, with $\lambda\ne0$, then
$$
AA^T(Ax)=\lambda Ax.
$$
And $Ax\ne0$ since $A^TAx\ne0$ (which follows from $\lambda\ne0$). This shows that every eigenvalue of $A^TA$ is an eigenvalue of $AA^T$. By exchanging the roles you get that eigenvalues are the same.

Alternatively, if $A=UDV$ is the singular value decomposition, then
$$
A^TA=V^TD^TDV,\ \  AA^T=UDD^TU^T.
$$
Since $D$ is "diagonal" (though rectangular), it is easy to see that all nonzero entries of $D^TD$ and $DD^T$ are the same.

Answer (score 1):

They have equal all eighevalues different from zero  because if $v$ is an eighevector of $A^tA$ of eighenvalue $\lambda\neq 0$  then

$A^tAv=\lambda v$

and  if you apply the matrix A you get

$AA^t(Av)=\lambda Av$
because $Av\neq 0$

(If $Av=0$ then $A^t(Av)=\lambda v=0$   and it is not possible because $v$ is an eighenvector of $A^tA$ and so it is different from zero. )

Comment: Note that the exclusion of $0$ as an eigenvalue comes from the fact that $Av$ might be zero, and this not an admissible eigenvector.

Comment: Sure thanks you for your remark

Comment: It's worth mentioning that just because the argument breaks down for $\lambda = 0$ doesn't mean the statement is false.  For that, the easiest way to disprove that case would be to provide a counterexample such as $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ for which $A^t A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \end{bmatrix}$ does not have 0 as an eigenvalue but $A A^t = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ does.  (In fact, for a non-square matrix, it's inevitable given the equality of ranks that one of the products will have 0 as an eigenvalue.)

Answer (score 1):

More generally, for any $n \times m$ matrix $A$ and $m \times n$ matrix $B$,
$AB$ and $BA$ have the same nonzero eigenvalues.

Comment: Blog post on the subject: https://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/06/05/ab-ba-and-the-spectrum/